# Argparse incorrect order of positional and optional parameters

Tags: python, command-line, command-line-arguments, argparse

Why won't argparse parse these arguments?

```
--foo 1 2 3 bar
```

Using

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--foo', nargs='+')                  
parser.add_argument('bar')
```

which gives the following error:

> error: too few arguments

If I pass the bar argument first though, it works:

```
bar --foo 1 2 3
```

Now, this in itself is not too bad. I can live with having the positional arguments first it's just that this behaviour is inconsistent with the help argparse creates for us, which states that bar should be last:

> usage: argparsetest.py [-h] [--foo FOO
>   [FOO ...]] bar

So how do you make this work with consistent help text?

Here's a complete [test program](http://paste.pocoo.org/show/381450/).

Comment: Ran into the same issue just now. One can use `--` to end `nargs` globbing, so `--foo 1 2 3 -- bar` should work in your example above. It really should be solved automatically, reserving the number of arguments needed for positional arguments, in my opinion. There are discussions on this open issue at http://bugs.python.org/issue9338 and http://bugs.python.org/issue9182 (at the very least it should be clearly documented).

Comment: `--` to stop the list is so cool. this is my favourite answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe try doing --input --output flags and setting those options to required=True in the add_argument?

http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#the-add-argument-method

Comment: Thanks, that works and gives me consistent help text. The only drawback is the extra --input flag part but I can live with that. Cheers

Comment: To clear things up, the suggested solution is to use parser.add_argument('--bar', required=True). One can then pass the following arguments: --foo 1 2 3 --bar bar

Answer (score 4):

`nargs='+'` tells argparse to gather all remaining args together, so `bar` is included. It has no magical way to guess you intend `bar` to be a meaningful argument by itself and not part of the args taken to `--foo`.

The example in the docs refers to a simple `--foo` argument, not one with `nargs='+'`. Be sure to understand the difference.

Comment: It would be easy to implement it so that the last n arguments are treated as the n mandatory positional arguments. It's not magic, I guess it's just a design decision.